# What's the xpath code for scraping this website?

Tags: web-scraping, xpath

I've been using the Scraper extension to scrape a website called Flippa and find websites for sale. For example, I'll go to this page with several websites on it and find all the domains for sale:

https://flippa.com/search?sort_alias=most_recent&filter%5Bproperty_type%5D=website,established_website,starter_site&filter%5Bsitetype%5D=content,blog,directory,review,forum-community

I've been using the following XPath code to gather the domains (e.g. blasterpiece.com), but it no longer works:

//div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a[2]/text()

Any idea what I need to tweak? I'm new to scraping, so I'm pretty stuck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This XPath should work: `//a[contains(@class,"GTM-search-result-card ng-binding")]/text()`